# React.js 18 and ethers 6 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Web3Provider')

Tags: ethers.js, react

```
"ethers": "^5.7.2",
"react": "^18.2.0",
```

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Web3Provider')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem,This is because your ether version is too high

You can solve it by downgrading ethers to version 5.x

```
"ethers": "^5.7.2",
```